# Can I still have persistent cookies on the local machine?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

Off the internet file:///C:/Users/etc, the new Firefox reads and writes JavaScript cookies only for the current session. Once the browser is closed the data that my old Firefox version kept in its cookie directory seems to disappear.
Offline, my Chrome browser doesn't allow local cookies at all.
Is there still a way to get data persistence on the local machine with document.cookies? Is it forbidden or is another way preferred? What is the safety issue here?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself but there's `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`, so the latter should persist values, I assume. OTOH, `localStorage` is hostname-based, so not sure if that'll work with any random HTML file. Also, this might be an XY problem. If you're creating an offline web app, electron might me a better choice.

Comment: Are you viewing the pages with `file:` URLs or `http:`/`https:` URLs talking to a local web server?

Comment: Yes file:/// but I like to keep it simple and just use a browser, not install Apache webserver or an IDE. This is just a JavaScript app I wrote for personal use, but I guess I could create a private webpage for it.
An alternative could be to trigger an onunload Event that opens a new page with a ?search query with the data string, so I should not forget to open that page next time to go on from where I left. I may try that.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies, and separately web storage (`localStorage` and `sessionStorage`) only really work for `http:` and `https:` resources, not `file:` resources. So if you're viewing your pages via `file:` URLs (`file:///home/user3057382/www/foo.html`, etc.), if Firefox stores cookies set by your JavaScript code during the session, that's Firefox going a bit of an extra mile, since cookies (specifically) are entirely an HTTP thing.

For local development, it's best to run a web server locally and view your pages and other resources over `http:` or `https:` (you can get a development-only local SSL certificate). Cookies (and web storage) will work normally with your pages then.

Most decent IDEs also have the ability to "run" your project with their built-in local web server, so you don't have to install and configure one yourself. Certainly Visual Studio Code, JetBrains, and the like do.

Comment: sorry, you  are right, i saw it to late that the point is that he has no webserver installed.